# How to optimize mysql equal connection query for speed?

Tags: mysql

I have upload sample table into dropbox.
[load into mysql with table name balance](https://www.dropbox.com/s/letr83wfi2702zr/balance.tb?dl=0)
[load into mysql with table name income](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yuo2r2dffj9gou/income.tb?dl=0)
Show data structure:

```
describe balance;
+----------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code                 | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| report_date          | date   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_assets         | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_owner_equities | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

describe income;
+--------------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code                     | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| report_date              | date   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total_operating_revenue  | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| net_profit               | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| np_parent_company_owners | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Both tables contain a little record in them.

```
select count(*) from income;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    51250 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)

select count(*) from balance;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    50832 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

It takes 4 minutes more to execute the equal connection query.

```
select a.code ,a.report_date ,a.total_assets ,a.total_owner_equities,  
       b.total_operating_revenue,b.net_profit ,b.np_parent_company_owners 
       from balance as a ,income  as b          
       where   a.code=b.code and a.report_date=b.report_date;


50793 rows in set (4 min 5.15 sec)
```

How to optimize mysql  equal connection query for speed in this case?

Comment: What are the primary keys of the tables, and what are the indexes in place? Please show us the output of `show create table` for both tables.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The reason the query is taking so long is that it is trying to match every record in the first table with every record in your second table. 51,250 * 50,832 = 2,605,140,000 checks.

By reducing the range, you can significantly increase your query speed.

---

### Code

```
select a.code ,a.report_date ,a.total_assets ,a.total_owner_equities,  
       b.total_operating_revenue,b.net_profit ,b.np_parent_company_owners 
       from balance as a ,income  as b          
       where   a.code=b.code and a.report_date=b.report_date
       and a.report_date between date1 and date2
       and b.report_date between samedate1 and samedate2;
```

Answer (score 0):

For up query performance you need couple of changes in your tables:

1. Not use text fields if it not necessary. So I mean `code` field can be changed to `VARCHAR` instead `TEXT`
2. Add index on fields used in joins.

So you need:

```
ALTER TABLE `TableA` 
CHANGE `code` VARCHAR(256),
ADD INDEX `code_idx` (`code`),
ADD INDEX `report_date_idx` (`report_date`);

ALTER TABLE `TableB` 
CHANGE `code` VARCHAR(256),
ADD INDEX `code_idx` (`code`),
ADD INDEX `report_date_idx` (`report_date`);
```

Comment: Do as your method,to add index and convert type for code,it takes more time to get query result--50793 rows in set (4 min 10.65 sec), 5 seconds more than before.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Can you provide the tables structure after they has altered in your question?